# Scraping with puppeteer and returning JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a node app that requires a URL from the user, the URL is then passed to `scrape.js` and using puppeteer, scrapes certain fields, and then passes the data back to `app.js` in a json format (so that I can then upset it into a doc). But what I receive is the entire ServerResponse and not the data in a json format as I'm intending.

I was hoping someone with more experience could shed some light. Here is what I have so far:

```
// app.js

const scrape = require('./scrape');
const router = express.Router();

router.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    const url = req.body.url;

    const item = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        scrape
            .scrapeData()
            .then((data) => res.json(data))
            .catch(err => reject('Scraping failed...'))
   })
});
```

```
// scrape.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scrapeData = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 360, height: 640 });
    await page.goto(url);

    let scrapedData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let scrapedDetails = [];

    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#a-page');

    elements.forEach(element => {
      let detailsJson = {};

      try {
        detailsJson.title = element.querySelector('h1#title').innerText;
        detailsJson.desc = element.querySelector('#description_box').innerText;
      } catch (exception) {}

    scrapedDetails.push(detailsJson);
  });

  return scrapedDetails;
  }));

  // console.dir(scrapeData) - logs the data successfully.

};

module.exports.scrapeData = scrapeData
```

Comment: It's hard to follow due to the indentation. But is it possible that the `scrapeData` function isn't returning anything?

Comment: @hardkoded, thanks for the reply! I can verify that it's returning data by console logging scrapeData in `scrape.js` which logs the data. Hang on I'll see if I can codesandbox an example!

Comment: lmao, never mind - TIL that you can't use puppeteer on codesandbox.

Comment: Your `Promise` never has `resolve` called, and it's not necessary anyway since `scrapeData()` [already returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Answer (score 1):

You have a naming problem. `scrape.js` is exporting the `scrapeData` **function**. Inside that function, you declared a `scrapedData` variable, which is not the same thing.

Where you put a:

```js
console.dir(scrapeData) - logs the data successfully.
```

Add

```
return scrapeData;
```

That should solve your issue.